# Finding the limit of a simple function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits

Studying for midterms.

> Let $f(x)=1$ if $x<=3$
>
> Let $f(x)=-1$ if $x>3$
>
> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> A) $\lim_{x\to3} f(x)$ does not exist.
>
> B) $\lim_{x\to3} f(x)=1$
>
> C) $\lim_{x\to3} f(x)=-1$
>
> D) None of the above is true.

Now I believe it's B) or $1$ since we're approaching 3 from the left side.
Since $x$ is always smaller or equal to 3 it should always be $1$, am I wrong?
I ask because there is no answer sheet.

Comment: why do you think that you approach 3 from the left side in b)?

Comment: Ah so if we're approaching it from both sides meaning the left side  limit is 1 and the right side limit is -1 meaning there is no limit?

Comment: yes, exactly! the symbol $\lim_{x\to3}$ means, that you can approach 3 in any way you like, and the result is always the same. Here (as you already said) we get -1 coming from right and +1 coming from left.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of a constant function is the constant, so The A) is not correct: if you approach 3 from the left side f(x) = 1, so the limit = 1. The C) isn't correct either since we're approaching 3 from the lest side, so the limit of f(x) will be 1. The B) is correct!

Comment: I don't think we're approaching B from the left side. If we were I think it'd be $\lim_{x->3^-}$